# When multiple index is used? And when to use Force Index?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I want exact difference between below tables according to performance.

I have dummy tables like this.

`CREATE TABLE multinindx1 (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  i int(11) NOT NULL,
  j int(11) NOT NULL,
  val char(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY i (i),
  KEY j (j)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

`CREATE TABLE multinindx2(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  i int(11) NOT NULL,
  j int(11) NOT NULL,
  val char(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY ij (i,j)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

If i want select 1M row from above tables which table is very much efficient to fetch data.

Note :- This are Just dummy tables actual table contain 16 Columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When are multiple indexes is used?

Short answer:  "Almost never".  It's called "index merge" in the online docs.  It is almost always better to use a composite index instead.

> And when to use Force Index?

Short answer:  "Almost never".  If you use `FORCE INDEX` for *today's* version of the query, you are likely to screw up the performance for *tomorrow's* version.

A complete answer is the size of a Master's thesis.  Or a full reading of the source code for MySQL.  Note further that different versions will give different answers.

Bits of the answer are in [Intro to compund indexing](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1) and [Cookbook for devising the best index for a given SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).  Both blogs address your pair of tables, although from different perspectives.

Since you have not provided any `SELECTs`, I am providing you a broad reply to your broad question.